# Nested ListView control

Tags: asp.net

i m having the following hierarchy in my aspx page

```
<asp:ListView ID="ListView1" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
         ...

         <asp:ListView ID="ListView2" DataKeyNames="statusID" runat="server"
             DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2" 
             ItemPlaceholderID="pl" 
             OnItemCommand="ListView2_ItemCommand">
                 <LayoutTemplate>
                      <asp:PlaceHolder ID="pl" runat="server"/>
                      ...
                      <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Post"/>
                 </LayoutTemplate>

                 <ItemTemplate>
                        ...
                 </ItemTemplate>
         </asp:ListView>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

now if i click Button2 then ListView2_ItemCommand event is fired.

```
protected void ListView2_ItemCommand(object sender, ListViewCommandEventArgs e)
```

inside the handler e.item is null, why?

Comment: I'm not %100 sure yet, but what is `e.CommandName` in the handler (when `e.item=null`)?

Comment: it is "" and that's ok because i hav not set the CommandName of Button2

Comment: i think Button2 is in LayoutTemplate thats why i am getting e.Item as null. But i want it to be there while still communicating with ListView2.

Comment: Why don't you just put it in the `ItemTemplate`?  Also, what do you *expect* to see in `e.Item`?

Answer (score 0):

there should be `ItemTemplate` with `CommandArgument`

E.g.

```
 <ItemTemplate>    
     <asp:ImageButton ID="ImgBtn" runat="server" CommandName="Select" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("ProductId")%>' />    
</ItemTemplate>
```

- ListView.ItemCommand [[MSDN]](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listview.itemcommand.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

1. How do you bind that controls? Check does ListView2 is not bind again after PostBack. If this is bind again Command will be canceled.
2. Why are you using nested list view? Did you consider using Groups http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.groups.aspx?

Comment: actually i have to access data from two different tables, so i hv used nested listview..

Answer (score 0):

In general, if you have a ListView lvInner nested inside a ListView lvOuter, use the handler lvOuter_ItemCommand and the CommandSource property of the ListViewCommandEventArgs.

The following worked for me:

```
protected void lvOuter_ItemCommand(object sender, ListViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    ListView lvInner = (ListView)e.Item.FindControl("lvInner");
    lvInner.SelectedIndex = lvInner.Items.IndexOf((ListViewDataItem)e.CommandSource);
    int innerID = (int)lvInner.SelectedDataKey["InnerID"];
    // etc.
}
```

Please note that in this case lvInner is nested inside the ItemTemplate of lvOuter.